# Move current lineargradient to top of an element

Tags: css

Im writing css code to add a dark theme to a website. One element is a lineargradient from the top to the bottom of a div. How can I change this element to have the lineargradient at the top only and #000 at the bottom?

Answer (score 0):

You could define a breakpoint where your #000 color starts as a percentage. For example setting

```css
background: linear-gradient(#555, #000 50%);
```

on your element would only display the gradient in the first 50% of its height and the rest would be black. It also works for colored gradients:

```css
background: linear-gradient(#0EB6F3, #002A65, #000 70%);
```